# scala json4s how can i extract field by condition

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I've got json(for example):

```
{
  "name": "",
  "count": 2,
  "children": {
    "app_open": {
      "name": "app_open",
      "count": 1,
      "children": {
        "session_end": {
          "name": "session_end",
          "count": 1,
          "children": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "app_install": {
      "name": "app_install",
      "count": 2,
      "children": {
        "session_end": {
          "name": "session_end",
          "count": 2,
          "children": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "app_instal1l": {
      "name": "app_instal1l",
      "count": 3,
      "children": {
        "app_open": {
          "name": "app_open",
          "count": 3,
          "children": {
            "session_end": {
              "name": "session_end",
              "count": 3,
              "children": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to extract all count where "name" = "app_open".

And I trying do it with json4s library:

```
val name = jsonInput filterField {
           case JField("name", "app_open") => true
           case _ => false
         }
println("name = " + URL)
```

And i suggest in output i'll have something with only "app_open", but i got:

```
name = List((name,JString(app_open)), (name,JString(session_end)), 
(name,JString(app_open)), (name,JString(session_end)))
```

What i'm doing wrong here? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler error is pretty clear:

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("app_open")
 required: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
    case JField("name", "app_open") => true
                    ^
```

That's because of `type JField = (String, JValue)`. Use `JValue` instead `String` like that:

```
val name = jsonInput filterField {
  case JField("name", JString("app_open")) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Note that JField is a type alias for ```(String, JValue)``` and could be matched without JField

Comment: Hm, i've got no errors while compilation, but your solution is working) Thank you!